# Single phase utility power connected to 3 phase system

Tags: electrical

Someone has connected a single phase utility temp power panel to a 3 phase system by using one of the phases twice. Is this ok

Comment: Is the "someone" a licensed electrician?  Are you saying they tapped 2 of the 3 phases?  What are the voltages involved?  This may be OK, or may not, depending on the particular setup in your area. **Are you in New York City or Brazil?**

Comment: Where on the planet are you?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I think they mean it the other way around, that they hooked up a split-phase feed from a temporary power pole to a building wired for three phase power, by wiring two of the building's phases to one of the pole's phase.  A->A; B->B+C.

Answer (score 2):

Using a three phase panel normally used with 208/120 three phase supply with 240/120 supply can be electrically sound and may even be code compliant.   But I am assuming the question is about a 240/120 split phase temporary power panel set on a pole, with a feeder running to an existing three phase panel that was installed with 208/120 three phase supply.  There could be a number of issues.

- If there are three phase motors or other loads connected for 208Y, they obviously are not going to run right and may be damaged.
- As mentioned in @Peter Green's answer, if there are multiwire branch circuits, you won't get the expected cancellation on neutral conductors, which could quickly result in overloaded on the neutrals.
- If there are 208V circuits for appliances etc. (water heaters, baseboard heaters, etc.) they may see 0V or 240V depending which two legs they are on.  Those that see 0V won't run at all (but don't be fooled and think those wires aren't hot).  Those that see 240V - some could be unaffected and run fine; some could run differently than expected; and some could be damaged.

Comment: Not just multiwire branch circuits, but also distribution circuits to subpanels and possibly circuits feeding equipment that takes multiple phases and the neutral.

Answer (score 1):

The main concern I would have with such a set-up is the potential for overloaded Neutral conductors. Assuming resistive loads, neutral currents from different phases will cancel such that the current in the neutral is no higher than the highest phase current. On the other hand Neutral currents from the same phase will not cancel.

Depending on the current rating of the temporary supply and the circuit arrangements fed from the panel this may or may not be an actual problem.